# Loading images from external storage using Core Graphics not working iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, nsurl, ios13

I am attempting to load photos located on external storage (SD card) using core graphics in iOS 13 (beta). The code below works fine when the files are on the device. When the files are on external storage  however it fails returning nil and I don't know why.

I believe I am using the correct security scoping. 
I loaded the file URLs from a security scoped folder url as per [Providing Access to Directories](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories)

```
guard folderUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
    return nil
}
defer { folderUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }

guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, options) else {
    throw Error.failedToOpenImage(message: "Failed to open image at \(imageURL)")
}
```

Comment: What error (if any) shows when you use `Data.init(contentsOf url: URL, 
options readOptionsMask: NSData.ReadingOptions = []) throws` to access the URL ?

Comment: alongside @WarrenBurton's comment, how are you sure that your `imageURL` contains anything?

Comment: Not that it really helps, but I have the exact same problem. External storage is behaving quite a bit different than local storage...

Comment: @WarrenBurton In my test case, CGImageSource... fails, but reading the file using NSData works just fine.

Comment: Another thing to check... do you actually get FILE urls, or does iOS sneakily give you directory references, like beta 7 does on my iPad?

Comment: When I use data.init it loads the expected amount of data without any issues. Because of that I’m pretty confident that I’m getting the file urls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... for my own project, where I ran into the same issue, I now have the following function to give me a thumbnail, going from elegant and quick to brute force.

```
static func thumbnailForImage(at url: URL, completion: (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) {
    let shouldStopAccessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    defer { if shouldStopAccessing { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() } }

    let coordinator = NSFileCoordinator()
    var error: NSError?

    coordinator.coordinate(readingItemAt: url, options: .withoutChanges, error: &error) { url in

        var thumbnailImage: UIImage?
        var storedError: NSError?
        var imageSource: CGImageSource?

        print("Strategy 1: Via URL resource key")
        do {
            let resourceKeys = Set([URLResourceKey.thumbnailDictionaryKey])
            let resources = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: resourceKeys)
            if let dict = resources.thumbnailDictionary, let resource = dict[URLThumbnailDictionaryItem.NSThumbnail1024x1024SizeKey] {
                thumbnailImage = resource
            } else {
                throw "No thumbnail dictionary"
            }
        } catch let error {
            storedError = error as NSError
        }

        let options = [kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true, kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat: true, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true]

        if thumbnailImage == nil {
            print("Strategy 2: Via CGImageSourceCreateWithURL")
            imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, options as CFDictionary)
        }

        if thumbnailImage == nil && imageSource == nil {
            print("Strategy 3: Via CGImageSourceCreateWithData")

            let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url)
            if let data = data {
                imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, options as CFDictionary)
            }
        }

        if let imageSource = imageSource, thumbnailImage == nil {
            print("Attempting thumbnail creation from source created in strategy 2 or 3")

            if let image = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options as CFDictionary) {
                thumbnailImage = UIImage(cgImage: image)
            }
        }

        if let thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage {
            print("Success")
            completion(.success(thumbnailImage))
        } else {
            print("Failure")
            if let error = storedError { completion(.failure(error)) }
            else { completion(.failure("Everything just fails...")) }
        }
    }

    if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)) }
}
```

Basically it works by trying to get a thumbnail via the URL resources first. This is the quickest and nicest way, of it works. If that fails, I try `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`. That works most of the time, except on remote storage. I suspect that's still a bug and submitted a feedback ticket to apple for this. I suggest you do the same. Last attempt, just try to read the entire file using `NSData` and creating an image source via `CGImageSourceCreateWithData`...

So far, if it's an image file I, this seems to produce a thumbnail most of the time. It can be quite slow though, having to read the entire file.

Comment: This is a good solution for now. Reading with data doesn’t seem to work on the Sony ARW RAW files I’m loading but it does from URL. I’m guessing this is due to the image loader not knowing what the file is due to not having an extension. RAW files are always hard to read. Loading from data works for JPEGs and PNG so that’ll do for now. 

I’ve also logged a ticket with Apple. Hopefully this is a bug that’ll be fixed soon!